# Django "before dispatch" mixin

Tags: python, django, inheritance, architecture

I am trying to define a mixin to set up a member and check for permissions before the view's dispatch is called but class hierarchy is "getting in the way". The behavior for a specific view would be:

```
class Page1View(TemplateView):
    # ...

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.object()
        if not object_permission(request.user, self.object):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(Page1View, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I would like to extract the bit before the `super().dispatch()` call into a mixin so that I can reuse it in different views:

```
class Page1View(TemplateView, BeforeDispatchMixin):
    # ...

class BeforeDispatchMixin(object):
    def get_object(self):
        # ...
        return object

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.object()
        if not object_permission(request.user, self.object):
            raise PermissionDenied
        # ???
        # here we would want to call the inheriting class' dispatch method
```

As per design doing what I am trying to do is impossible. What's an alternative here?

Answer (score 2):

`super` follows the MRO (Method Resolution Order) chain in case of multiple inheritances, and the only caveat is that all the superclasses must call `super` on that method to call the same method of the next superclass of the MRO (inheritance) chain. So you can think of it being a *co-operative* operation.

In your case, you need to prepend some operations before `TemplateView.dispatch`, so it's a good idea to put the Mixin first in the inheritance order:

```
class Page1View(BeforeDispatchMixin, TemplateView):
    ...
```

Now make sure to call `super` from the `BeforeDispatchMixin.dispatch` method to refer `TemplateView.dispatch` eventually:

```
class BeforeDispatchMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.object()
        if not object_permission(request.user, self.object):
            raise PermissionDenied

        # This will now call the next superclass's `dispatch`, which
        # happens to be `TemplateView.dispatch` in your example
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but keep in mind that the `TemplateView` or other generic views is in the right most.

```
class Page1View(BeforeDispatchMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...

class BeforeDispatchMixin(object):
    def get_object(self):
        # ...
        return object

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.object()
        if not object_permission(request.user, self.object):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can read more about MRO in python here https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/